# HttpCookie.Path and mapped urls

Tags: c#, asp.net, cookies, url-routing, relative-path

According to the official documentation page [HttpCookie.Path](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcookie.path%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) :

> The Path property extends the Domain property to completely describe the specific URL to  which the cookie applies. For example, in the URL http:/www.microsoft.com/asp, the domain is www.microsoft.com and the path is /asp.

and then they provide an example: `MyCookie.Path = "/asp";`

The previous statements in my opinion create more questions than answers.
So my question is what happens if i set the cookie like the previous example and i have a mapped route like `/asp/{id}`? Will work either?

Also will affect if i define the path without the `/` just with `asp`?
And one more question, what's the scope of the previous setting (i mean from what urls i can read the cookie)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the answer on another [official page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178194%28v=vs.140%29.aspx) in small letters they write:

> The path can either be a physical path under the site root or a virtual root. The effect will be that the cookie is available only to pages in the Application1 folder or virtual root. For example, if your site is called www.contoso.com, the cookie created in the previous example will be available to pages with the path http://www.contoso.com/Application1/ and to any pages beneath that folder. However, the cookie will not be available to pages in other applications such as http://www.contoso.com/Application2/ or just http://www.contoso.com/.

Example:

```
HttpCookie appCookie = new HttpCookie("AppCookie");
appCookie.Value = "written " + DateTime.Now.ToString();
appCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1);
appCookie.Path = "/Application1";
Response.Cookies.Add(appCookie);
```

They also talk about something similar `Domain` scope:

> By default, cookies are associated with a specific domain. For example, if your site is www.contoso.com, the cookies you write are sent to the server when users request any page from that site. (This might not include cookies with a specific path value.) If your site has subdomains—for example, contoso.com, sales.contoso.com, and support.contoso.com—then you can associate cookies with a specific subdomain. To do so, set the cookie's Domain property, as in this example:

```
Response.Cookies["domain"].Value = DateTime.Now.ToString();
Response.Cookies["domain"].Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1);
Response.Cookies["domain"].Domain = "support.contoso.com";
```

> When the domain is set in this way, the cookie will be available only to pages in the specified subdomain. You can also use the Domain property to create a cookie that can be shared among multiple subdomains, as shown in the following example:

```
//The cookie will then be available to the primary domain as well as to sales.contoso.com and support.contoso.com domains.
Response.Cookies["domain"].Value = DateTime.Now.ToString();
Response.Cookies["domain"].Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1);
Response.Cookies["domain"].Domain = "contoso.com";
```

Answer (score -1):

I have change cookie path with following code. Hope it will work for you also.

```
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(new HttpCookie("ASP.NET_SessionId") { Path = "/Application", Value = newID });
```